# laravel ajax form won't execute submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Basically my form adds to blade by help of javascript and then i can fulfill data and hit the save button.

**The issue is save button doesn't work.**

**[Here is screen record of the process and error you can watch](https://streamable.com/ejeoe)**

## Code

This function will add new row and form to view where you see in video i filled input and hit save button

```
var textFieldsCount = 0;

  function addTextField(){
    textFieldsCount++;
    var textfieldhelper = '';
    var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20" id="textField-' + textFieldsCount + '">');
    var my_html = '{{Form::open()}}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><div class="col-md-4">{{ Form::label('customsubspecifications', 'Specifications') }}<select class="form-control" id="specification_id" name="specification_id"><option value="">Select</option>'+specifications+'</select></div>';
    my_html += '<div class="col-md-4">{{ Form::label('text_dec', 'Your Custom Input') }}'+
    '<input class="text_dec form-control" onkeypress="myFunction()" type="text" name="text_dec[]" id="'+ textFieldsCount.toString() +'">'+
    '</div>';
    my_html += '<div class="col-md-4">{{ Form::label('', 'Actions') }}<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="removeTextField(\'textField-' + textFieldsCount.toString() + '\')">Remove</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="addTextField();">Add New</button><button type="button" id="custmodalsave" class="myButton custmodalsave btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
    my_row.html(my_html);
    $('#fields').append(my_row);
  }
```

here is where thing happen and I actually try to send data to back-end

```
$("#custmodalsave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('admin/addnewcustomsubspecifications') }}",
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': $('#product_id').val(),
          'specification_id': $('#specification_id').val(),
          'text_dec': $('.text_dec').val(),
          'longtext_dec': $('.longtext_dec').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $('#custspacmsg').append('<span class="text-success">Custom Specification added successfully in your product!</span>');
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error:', data);
        }
      });
});
```

> just to be clear I attached output form of my first ajax code so you
>   can see how things are printed

```
<div class="row mt-20" id="textField-1">

    <form method="POST" action="http://newsite.pp/admin/products/15" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input name="_token" value="DLrcOa0eOm90e4aaGSYp2uCeiuKtbGCT9fCOUP16" type="hidden">
        <input name="product_id" id="product_id" value="15" type="hidden">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="customsubspecifications">Specifications</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="specification_id" name="specification_id">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="1">CPU</option>
                <option value="2">ram</option>
                <option value="3">LCD</option>
                <option value="4">Mouse</option>
                <option value="5">Graphic</option>
                <option value="6">Keyboard</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="text_dec">Your Custom Input</label>
            <input class="text_dec form-control" onkeypress="myFunction()" name="text_dec[]" id="1" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="">Actions</label>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="removeTextField('textField-1')">Remove</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="addTextField();">Add New</button>
            <button type="button" id="custmodalsave" class="myButton custmodalsave btn btn-xs btn-success" style="display: inline-block;">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

> PS: I should add that I have this function working on bootstrap modal
>   but i wanted to change modal the way you see in video (print by click in blade)
>   Back-End is working perfectly since I can save data by this Ajax code with modal. Whatever the issue is, is coming from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining your click function as

```
$("#custmodalsave").click(function(e){
```

But, when this function is defined, `$("#custmodalsave")` is not available in your DOM as you're appending it:

```
$('#fields').append(my_row); // my_row contains `[...] id="custmodalsave"`
```

To fix this, simply use event delegation:

```
$("body").on("click", "#custmodalsave", function(e){ ... });
```

For more info on event delegation, please check out the jQuery reference:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: OH MY! :) love you man :D  appreciate it  (please wait few min till i be allow to accept your answer)

Comment: No problem :) Btw, cheers for the combination of your code and the concise video; makes it a breeze to identify problems like this.